# Printing a string in reverse order using stacks and vectors in C++

Tags: c++, stack

Quick question: I am trying to accept a string parameter and then print it backwards using stacks and vectors. However, nothing is printed to the screen after it says Here you go!. I believe it has something to do with the vector setup, as I have never worked with this before. Here is the code in question. I would appreciate any help!

```
void main() {

stack<char> S;
string line;
vector<char> putThingsHere(line.begin(), line.end());
vector<char>::iterator it;

cout << "Insert a string that you want to see backwards!" << endl;
cin >> line;

for(it = putThingsHere.begin(); it != putThingsHere.end(); it++){
    S.push(*it);
}

cout << "Here you go! " << endl; 

while(!S.empty()) {
    cout << S.top();
    S.pop();
}

system("pause");


}
```

Comment: `void main()` is non-standard. Use `int main()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vector is being initialized too early, when `line` is still empty. Move the construction of `putThingsHere` *below* the instruction that extracts the string from the standard input:

```
cin >> line;
vector<char> putThingsHere(line.begin(), line.end());
```

Here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3ji7qM%2427) of your fixed program running correctly.

Notice the use of `getline()` instead of `cin >> line`, so that whitespaces in between your characters could still be read as part of one single string.

This said, it is worth mentioning that `std::string` satisfies the requirements of standard sequence containers and, in particular, has member functions `begin()` and `end()` returning an `std::string::iterator`.

Therefore, you do not need an `std::vector<>` at all and the snippet below will do the job:

```
getline(cin, line);
for(std::string::iterator it = line.begin(); it != line.end(); it++) {
    S.push(*it);
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it, but I would mention to use `getline` to read a variable called `line`.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much. Glad to know that I had it mostly right and it was just order that I overlooked. Thanks for the live coding example!

Answer (score 2):

Your `line` variable is initially empty. You never really put anything inside the `vector` PutThingsHere and `stack` S.

Put the

```
cout << "Insert a string that you want to see backwards!" << endl;
cin >> line;
```

before the `vector<char> PutThingsHere(...)` statement.

Answer (score 0):

First read into `line` and only then `putThingsTHere`

```
stack<char> S;
string line;

cout << "Insert a string that you want to see backwards!" << endl;
cin >> line;
vector<char> putThingsHere(line.begin(), line.end());
vector<char>::iterator it;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've your using `std::string` already, why not use:

```
`std::string reversed(line.rend(), line.rbegin());`
```

Comment: I kind of got the idea from the title and code that it was a stack exercise. I agree that this, along with `std::reverse` are both easy ways to do it, though. In fact, if just outputting, you can `std::reverse_copy` it to a `std::ostream_iterator`.

Comment: I had wondered if that was a constraint of the question, but sometimes it's hard to tell when something's an exercise or when it's something they're trying to accomplish :-)